# Callback qml function invoke segfault

Tags: qt, callback, qml, dbus

I'm implementing callback of qml function in c++ code. Let me explain what i want to have, when all will work (it will, i believe ;) ).

I have two sides:
One one side - qml project with gui and c++ plugin with dbus interface.

On other side - something that just process incomming dbus messages and answer.

---

I want to invoke some function in qml code:

```
    Component.onCompleted: {
    A.request1( function(arg) {console.log('Callback func invoked - ', arg)} )
```

In c++ plugin i do this:

```
    class A () {
    public:
      request1(QJSValue callback_func) {
        QList<QVariant> args;
        QDBusPendingCall pcall = interface->asyncCallWithArgumentList(QString("GetMachineId"), args);
        QDBusPendingCallWatcher *watcher = new QDBusPendingCallWatcher(pcall, this);
        QObject::connect(watcher, SIGNAL(finished(QDBusPendingCallWatcher*)),
                         this, SLOT(response1(QDBusPendingCallWatcher*)));
        qjs_value = callback_func;
      }
    public slots:
      void response1(QDBusPendingCallWatcher* w) {
        cout << "Debug message1";
        qjs_value.call(QJSValueList() << 'Some text');
      }
    private: 
      QJSValue qjs_value;  
    }
```

Dbus send message, receive answer, Watcher catch reply, initiate SIGNAL, that connected to SLOT "response1".
I see debug message "Debug message1", so i think "response1()" function is invoked correctly. But that, on next line

```
         qjs_value.call(QJSValueList() << 'Some text');
```

i get a segfault and i can't understand the reason of it.

One more thing: if i invoke callback qjs_value.call in request1() function - it works correctly and i see "Callback func invoked - Some text". But it doesn't work in way that i described.

Do you have some ideas?

Comment: Possibly because in C++ single quotes are for single characters only. You should put "Some text" in double quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the response1 slot is not executed in the GUI thread? Just try to connect it as a "Queued" connection?